# How to plot a graph with text file (2 columns of data) in Python

Tags: python, graph, text-files

I have a text file with lots of data that is arranged in 2 columns. I need to use the data in the 2nd column in a formula (which outputs Energy). I need to plot that energy against the time which is all the data in the first column.
So far I have this, and it prints a very weird graph. I know that the energy should be oscillating and decaying exponentially.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = 0.090
l = 0.089
g = 9.81

H = np.loadtxt("AngPosition_3p5cmSeparation.txt")
x, y = np.hsplit(H,2)
Ep = m*g*l*(1-np.cos(y))
plt.plot(x, Ep)
plt.show()
```

I'm struggling to see where I have gone wrong, but then again I am somewhat new to Python. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: PS: I have tried splitting the data in two separate files and the same graph is still shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. My problem was that the angle data had to be converted into radians.
I couldn't do that automatically in Python using `math.radians` for some reason so I just edited the data in Excel and then back into Notepad.